# Why is my raw HTML content appearing below the footer?

Tags: squarespace

I have a raw HTML page on my SquareSpace site and I've built a table inside it.

For some reason my SquareSpace footer (and all the spacing that goes with it) is appearing ABOVE the HTML I'm writing.

My suspicion is that it's the `<table>` tag itself causing the issue because the `<h2>` tag and accompanying content appears above the footer. And if I use another common tag, like `<b>`, it appears above the footer as well.

Any ideas?

[Here is the page in question](http://www.etpnebraska.com/products/)

Comment: Link please so we can check it out?

Comment: you want to give us a link to the site so we can actually see what you're talking about?  you aren't going to get a helpful answer when all you tell us is basically "my code doesn't work"

Comment: Sorry about that. [The page in question](http://www.etpnebraska.com/products/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forgetting the closing tag

```
                        <td><p>230 VAC<br />

                          32 A</p></td>

                        <td><p>IEC 62196-2 <br />

                          e-mobility Type-2</p></td>

                        <td><p>Bollard</p></td>

                        <td>Europe</td>

                        <td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/UI7oC.jpg" width="50" height="80" alt="CT2500" /></td>

                      </tr>
[needs a closing table tag here]



</div></div> <!-- Content -->



    </div></div> <!-- Page Body -->



    <div id="pageFooterWrapper"><div id="pageFooter">

              Copyright &copy; 2012, Electric Transportation Partners | Nebraska.  All rights reserved.




    </div></div>
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. I'm a dunce.

Comment: No problem. Did virtually the exact same thing myself once xD